# How to make image click-able and work to load next image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help!

I need to add a function that when we click on main image it works like next arrow on right side on following page. In other words i want to add main image click-able and works same as the next image arrow is working.

http://kswebproducts.com/photography/one/

Click on any image and it will open up in lightbox, here i want the main image click-able and work like the next arrow on right.

Comment: No easy way to do it. Just use a jQuery selector for the image such as: `$([whateverYourImageis]).on('click', function() {$('a.tos-next').click()});` Not the best approach to the problem, but since there is no true click function, it'll simulate the arrow being clicked.

Comment: I did it through CSS by expanding the click-able area on both right and left. This seems working good. You can check on link above. Thanks for help guys!